# How do I create a new class or struct with property of its own type?

Tags: object-oriented, recursion

I have been trying to figure out if I can create a class or struct with a property that is of the same class or struct. An example would be

```
struct Number { 
    var Value: Int = 0
    var Rate: Number() //Default value for rate would be 0
 }
```

Effectively this would be a recursive line of code but I don't want it to execute more than one iteration down. That is to say, if I have a timer to increment all Numbers by their given rates. But some of the rates also have rates also need to be incremented with the timer. I could declare all all of the individual properties and their prospective rates, but this seemed like a potentially good way to save on code. I just can't seem to wrap my head around the recursive nature of the idea. Declaring a variable that declares a variable that declares a ...

If anyone would be willing to help me understand how this would work, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Making it a struct would be problematic for obvious reasons. If you make it a class however you will be fine.

The Rate member would initially be null or you could have Rate's constructor create a Rate instance but that would have to be done conditionally: only when the Rate object's parent is null. You would pass parent to the constructor as an argument. This would give you your one-level deep nested Rate object.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. So the way to write the code for this would be to change the line for rate to `var? Rate: Number()` or whatever it needs to be in the given language. I think I'm kind of mixing up languages but I'm trying to learn several at once. That makes sense.

Comment: @Timothy You must make Rate a class and you do not need the ? after var. I assume the ? declares a nullable (value) type which would still be a struct, which occupies a fixed amount of inline memory. This would recursively deplete memory if the compiler would allow you to do this. A class would make the Rate member a reference which would be fine. I am not entirely sure your compiler will handle nullable types in structs the way I described, it may default to references after all and also work but then it would defeat the purpose of using structs. Anyway, you may want to try both.